# How to replace more than one keyword in a string in MYSQL using REPLACE and regex

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I have sets of field values in mysql table like

```
aaaworld
worldme
make
pull
pullme
aaatag
tagbbb
aaamousebbb
```

Now I want to remove every occurance of aaa and bbb and replace the same with "",
I tried with below expression

```
SELECT REPLACE(keywordSupplied,"aaa|bbb","") FROM table1
```

here it is replacing only the aaa part with "" while bbb part remains as it is.
How can I replace occurances of both

Comment: Like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d206/1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "||" instead of "|".It might work.